# Deserializing JSON to KeyValuePairs<string, CustomClass>

Tags: json, swift

I am receiving a JSON-structure in Swift via a WebApi which contains a dictionary. I am deserializing this structure to a Swift-Object which works perfectly. The swift-object therefore contains an attribute of Dictionary.

I have to display the data of this dictionary in a TableView but the problem is that Dictionary does not guarantee the order. So everytime I am reloading the data via WebApi, the ordering in the table changes.

I already investigated a lot and found that KeyValuePairs could be an option.

1) Deserializing the JSON directly to KeyValuePairs which does not work currently because KeyValuePairs does not implement the protocol "Decodable"

2) Deserializing the JSON to Dictionary and convert that Dictionary to an KeyValuePairs and use this data-structure to display the TableView. But I don't know how to do this?

Can anybode help me with 1) and 2). Thanks!

Comment: A concrete solution depends highly on the concrete data and code. A common solution is a custom `init(from decoder)` method in the affected struct to map the dictionary to something suitable. Most likely a third party library is not needed.

Comment: This is not possible. JSONDecoder is built on top of NSJSONSerialization, which destroys the order (and eliminates duplicates) before the Codable system can even look at the data. (Marked duplicate; if you believe there is a difference, let me know and we can reopen it, but your web API is broken. JSON does not promise order, and Foundation does not have tools to fix broken JSON.)